# Sendmail: can't send mail even the stat=send

Tags: linux, email, centos, sendmail

It was working previously but one day suddenly we cannot send out any mail. Sometimes the maillog show the stat as "Data Format Error" or "send". but neither it's actually sending the mail.

On the same day that it stops working, we had a problem that we lack disk space but we have already free out some space. Wonder if the disk space does with anything.

We checked our firewall setting, it should be fine.

This is part of our maillog:

```
 Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30535]: u5G4VQFU030535: from=root, size=74, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201606160431.u5G4VQFU030535@exampleserver>, relay=root@localhost
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30536]: u5G4VQdk030536: from=<root@exampleserver>, size=320, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201606160431.u5G4VQFU030535@exampleserver>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30535]: u5G4VQFU030535: to=testing@destination.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30074, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u5G4VQdk030536 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30538]: STARTTLS=client, relay=testing2.destination.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30538]: u5G4VQdk030536: to=<testing@destination.com>, ctladdr=<root@exampleserver> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120320, relay=hku-nsp2.destination.com. [147.8.145.28], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30538]: u5G4VQdk030536: u5G4VQdk030538: DSN: Data format error
Jun 16 12:31:26 exampleserver sendmail[30538]: u5G4VQdk030538: to=<root@exampleserver>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31526, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Will anyone able to tell where the problem is? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post bounce message sent  back to `root` user?  It should contain more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
How to we search back the bounce message?

Comment: we have not setup an receive email address so we can only send out emails.

Comment: A new information: gmail can receive my email. Not Yahoo. Not our own server...the error message is "Data format error"

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I have to add my IP address and domain name to /etc/host file to let the receiving host know who we are.